Is there a way to keep oauth2 token for infinite time?
I am trying to build an app for scheduling youtube content,
here is how the app works=>

user signs in through google (I get his oauth2 token with youtube scope added)
uploads a video on my site and gives me a time to post it

my question is:
the oauth2 token will expire after a few weeks, what if the user wants me to post the video after 3 months , but he does not want to login to my app. Is there a way I can keep the token alive?
I am just learning so please be humble, This is surely possible because companies like hootsuite, zoho are achieving exactly this ,but how?

OAuth2 has a refresh mechanism that lets you obtain a new token

@evert yes but that requires users to sign in right , I dont want my user to signin again and again

No it does not.

can you link any appropirate docs, Ill be very happy to accept this answer

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-6

You need to get refresh token and use it to obtain a new access token without user interaction. To get refresh token and exchange for a new access token, you need to implement them in your back-end for security reason.

thank you so much exactly what I was looking for, just one more thing is this possible with nextauth

I am not familiar with NextAuth. You may want to direct your question directly to their support. However, just a quick look at this, assuming it is the same library you are referring to, it looks like NextAuth does support the refresh token flow.
